# SQL query using IN clause to select both conditions, not either or

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a query using an "in" clause where I need everything in the IN clause to be true, i.e., Only records from myTable that have both nbrs 10 and 1. Currently I'm getting records for either 1 OR 10. I've been scouring SQL sites and just can't seem to figure this out. The list could be longer which is why I'm using an IN claus. Any ideas?

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable INNER JOIN
     myTable2
WHERE myTable.ID = myTable2.ID AND myTable2.nbr in ('10','1')
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  How can MyTable2.nbr be equal to both '10' and '1' at the same time?  Can you post some sample data for a table and a sample for the desired result set?

Comment: Please show the table layout, sample data, and desired results.

Comment: Sounds like you properly need to use an EXISTS instead of IN

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? You can generally accomplish this by comparing the `COUNT(DISTINCT nbr)` to the total number of possible values in the `IN ()` clause.

Comment: Why is table2.nbr a text field and not a numeric? Are you actually looking for `SELECT * FROM myTable mt INNER JOIN myTable2 mt2 ON mt.ID = mt2.ID WHERE ( mt.nbr = 10 AND mt2.nbr = 1 ) OR ( mt.nbr = 1 AND mt2.nbr = 10 )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT myTable.ID 
    FROM myTable 
         INNER JOIN myTable2
               ON myTable.ID = myTable2.ID 
              AND table2.nbr IN ('10','1')
  GROUP BY myTable.ID 
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT table2.nbr) = 2 -- replace 2 with the number of elements in `IN` list
```

Comment: This scales much better than my answer.  I missed the part about the list possibly being longer.  Upvote for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might give you what you want.  If not, you will need to post some sample data.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable mt
INNER JOIN   myTable2 mt21 on mt.id = mt21.id and mt21.nbr = '1'
INNER JOIN   myTable2 mt22 on mt.id = mt22.id and mt22.nbr = '10'
```

EDIT: Although the accepted answer scales more easily, this solution is probably going to return faster results.

Answer (score 0):

Using exists will give you what I believe is the desired result.  You can continue to append `AND` clauses in this fashion for each item that is required in the list.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable INNER JOIN myTable2 ON myTable.ID = myTable2.ID
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM myTable2 subTbl WHERE subTbl.ID=myTable2.ID AND subTbl.nbr='1')
  AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM myTable2 subTbl2 WHERE subTbl2.ID=myTable2.ID AND subTbl2.nbr='10')
```